# Разное форматирование строк в одной ячейке

Tags: excel, visual-basic, ms-word

Ситуация: Есть список имен и компаний. Нужно сделать бейджи для них. В конечной форме на бейдже имя имеет одно форматирование (24 шрифт, к примеру), а название компании другое (16 шрифт). 
Проблема: при соединении ячеек в одной пропадает форматирование. Соответственно имя и компания становятся одного размера.

Есть ли возможность соединить ячейки с разным форматированием? Возможно, есть какой-то более адекватный способ, не связанный со сцеплением ячеек?

Ниже скрин того, в каком формате есть данные и того, как то должно выглядеть в конечной форме.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Формулами в *Excel* никак не получится - они не умеют форматировать ячейки. Можно было бы применить условное форматирование, но опять незадача - *УФ* не сможет изменить формат части текста, только все символы.

Вариант 1. Каждый бейджик разместить в двух строках с разным форматированием ячеек. В неизменяемом тексте можно форматировать хоть каждый сивол по отдельности, но если значение подставляется в ячейку формулой, то формат должен быть единым.

Вариант 2. Воспользоваться услугами макросов. В *VBA* есть набор операторов, отвечающих за форматирование (размер, вид, тип шрифта, заливка. обрамление и т.д.). А чтобы узнать, какую часть текста форматировать, зовите на помощь оператор *Characters*. Простор для форматирования :)

Пример кода, демонстрирующий форматирование частей текста. Макрос пробегает по строкам, объединяет и форматирует текст

```
Sub FormatText()
Dim sName As String, sComp As String
Dim i As Long, n As Long, k As Long
    For i = 2 To 10 ' цикл по строкам'
        sName = Cells(i, 1).Value ' имя в переменную'
        n = Len(sName) ' длина имени'
        sComp = Cells(i, 2).Value ' компания в переменную'
        k = Len(sComp) ' длина названия'

        With Cells(i, 3)
            .Value = sName & Chr$(10) & sComp ' записываем в ячейку объединенный текст с переносом строки'
            .Characters(1, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 100, 100) ' первая буква красная'

            With .Characters(1, n).Font ' шрифт для фрагмента текста (с символа 1 длина n)'
                .Bold = True: .Name = "Arial": .Size = 26 ' жирный Arial 26'
            End With

            With .Characters(n + 2, k).Font ' шрифт для фрагмента текста (с символа n+2 длина k)'
                .Italic = True: .Name = "Calibri": .Size = 18 ' курсив Calibri 18'
            End With
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]